# Moving from UK to Germany - Open pension account to later buy house

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, pension

Hope the question isn't too convoluted, but here goes:
We are moving to Germany, permanently, into full time employed roles - from the UK where we currently have our own business.
To reduce my business tax obligation here in the UK it was suggested by my accountant that I add funds to my pension.

I'd like to add those funds to a German pension plan which later allows me to apply some or all of those funds towards the purchase of a house and increase my down payment - but it of course needs to be seen by HMRC as a 'regular' pension plan in Germany.

Questions are:

1. Can I do this / do you know of any plans that allow this?
2. Can I open the German pension plan now (a month before I arrive there and start work / have a bank account, etc... this is necessary to move the funds to the pension plan before my business year end at the end of this month?
3. If 2 can't happen, can I move the funds to a UK pension plan now and then transfer them next month to a German plan (and how would that work)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic: it requires legal input by both tax attorney and the German State tax authorities .